# Self referential classes and class loader in java

Tags: java, class, jvm, self-reference

In following class definition in Java

```
public class Node{

private Node next;
//other fields

// getter setter 

}
```

In above class definition class contain a link to self type as `next`.

How this class is loaded in JVM as I see , this is a recursive definition ?

Comment: The value of `next` is unlikely to link to *self* (aka `this`). It more likely links to another *instance* of the class, or doesn't link to anything (`null`).

Answer (score 1):

Class loader loads a class only once. The `next` field of the class simply indicates that the field named next is a `Node` type.(JVM's static area)
It is the Instance that can have a recursive relation. (JVM's heap area)

```java
Node node1 = new Node();    
node1.setNext(node1);
```

In this case, there is only one instance created in the Heap area.
The `next` in the stack area is will point to the address of the node1 instance.